# What is a good introductory reference for ZFC theory?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, set-theory

I am an analyst studying functional analysis and PDE’s. What would be a good introductory reference to study Zermelo-Fraenke theory + Axiom of Choice (which is used in functional analysis)?

Comment: It would help if you described your background knowledge better. For example, have you studied undergraduate logic and set theory at roughly the level of Enderton's texts ([set theory](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0122384407) and [logic](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0122384520))? If not, then maybe consider something like Enderton's set theory text or [Hrbacek/Jech's set theory text](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0824779150). If yes, then maybe consider something like [Kunen's text](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0444868399). Of course, none of these is particularly aimed at functional analysts.

Comment: Incidentally, the mathoverflow questions [Finding questions between functional analysis and set theory](https://mathoverflow.net/q/19014/15780) and [Set-theoretic reformulation of the invariant subspace problem](https://mathoverflow.net/q/136157/15780), and the survey [*Descriptive set theory and operator algebras*](https://www.birs.ca/workshops/2012/12w5099/report12w5099.pdf) may be of interest to you.